# Can I import .DMP file in any database? no vendor dependency?

Tags: mysql, database, oracle

I have database .DMP file.

How can I find its respective database and if I can import it using any of the database whether it is MySQL or Oracle

Answer (score 1):

If by .DMP file you mean an Oracle export produced by Oracle's `exp` utility then you cannot use it with any other DBMS.  It is an Oracle proprietary format.

But having re-read your question I gather you don't even know what database produced your file.  In that case I think you're probably out of luck.  You see, .DMP is just a convention, it's not a naming standard.  You could trying `strings` against it: that might give you enough information to tell what database it came from, but the chances are you will only be able to import it into the same database.

One exception is if it is a MySQL dump, as that produces a text file of SQL statements.  So you could import that into another flavour of database, although you would probably need to translate the SQL commands into the different dialect,